# How to generate excel like report in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services

I have this [Excel Sheet](https://www.mediafire.com/?8e0517wha7zsslb) That I want to generate from my WPF Application, What is the easiest way to do so, bear in mind that the table in the sheet may have many containers and each container may have one or more sizes and so on as shown.

I'v looked at the ReportViewer provided in WPF but I don't know how to design such a report using the ReportViewer.

Another thing came to my mind is to fill the excel sheet from the WPF and I found a way to do so by specifying tags (Ex: Date:  ) in which I can fill these tags from my WPF application, but I don't know who to generate tables and set their columns and rows according to the data in the database.

Thank you.

Comment: try [ClosedXml](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) . Its opensource , OpenXml is used to create this . No need of office installation. Easy way to generate excel files

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` as a dll, and try the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665176/how-to-write-to-excel-file-using-datarow-in-c-sharp-wpf).

Or have a look at this sample:

[WPF Spreadsheet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/712093/WPF-Spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

I have made good experience with the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library. The nice thing is, you don't need any MS Office components on your OS to generate the excel files.